# WordPress MultiSite Redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

A large multi-network wordpress site is auto directing users to the root domain.

Everytime I go to `http://sitename.com/username/wp-admin` it looks like this:

`http://sitename.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fsitename.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1`

Here is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I've tried disabling all plugins.